# .some() function not working with nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I want to check whether `arr1` (an array of 3 arrays) contains any element of `arr2` (an array of 2 arrays), I use the `.some()` function, but it returns `false`.

```
let arr1 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
let arr2 = [[1, 2], [5, 2],]

if (arr1.some(x => arr2.includes(x))) {
    alert('arr1 has arr2')
};
```

x does return the array [1, 2], but for some reason it doesn't pass the check for .some() in arr1.

Comment: Each of those arrays is a unique object. Object comparison in JavaScript is based on object identity, not object content.

Comment: alert('arr1 has arr2') missing semicolom? `alert('arr1 has arr2');`

Answer (score 3):

`.includes` will return `true` if the passed item is `===` to one in the array, but separate objects are never `===` to each other in JS unless one was created from a reference from the other:

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
console.log(arr === [1, 2]);
const arr2 = arr; // same reference
console.log(arr === arr2);
```

. I suppose one method would be to stringify the subarrays first:

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
let arr2 = [[1, 2], [5, 2],]

if (arr1.some((subarr1) => {
  const str1 = JSON.stringify(subarr1);
  return arr2.some(subarr2 => JSON.stringify(subarr2) === str1);
})) {
    console.log('arr1 has arr2')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think includes function isn't working for arrays 2 dimension
Please change code like this

```
let arr1 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
let arr2 = [[1, 2], [5, 2],]
if (arr1.some(x => {
    return arr2.some(item => item.toString() === x.toString())
})) {
    alert('arr1 has arr2')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you `_.isEqual`of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual) to compare the Array.

```js
let arr1 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
let arr2 = [[1, 2], [5, 2]]

if (arr1.some(x => {
    return arr2.some(item => _.isEqual(item, x))
})) {
    console.log('arr1 has arr2')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```